# MongoDB geospatial query does not return anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, 2dsphere

I have a collection with a `2dsphere` index and want to use the `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere` functions to query it.

Excerpt of the model:

```
{
// ...
coordinates: {
    coordinates: {
        type: Array,
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
}
// ...
}
```

I successfully inserted a bunch of documents into the database and now try to query it via:

```
Model.find({
    coordinates: {
        coordinates: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere : [ [ lng, lat], r ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The problem I am facing is, that the call does not return anything, neither an error, nor data. I tried it in the `mongo shell` as well as in my `node.js` application with longitudes and latitudes of objects I can confirm were inserted into the database. I also tried to use `$near` with a `$maxDistance` with the same result. I furthermore switched latitude and longitude just to check...and I do convert `r` to radians by dividing by the earth's radius.

I am out of ideas on what goes wrong at this point and thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: Try "coordinates.coordinates" rather than nesting objects. Not sure why you would structure this way anyhhow. But if you are actually not showing your full schema than this is a good reason why this would fail. Also., though not required for `$geoWithin`, have you actually defined a "2dsphere" index? For the `$geoWithin` operator you do not need it (but it helps), but for `$near` or similar you do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As shown in the Model-excerpt above I did define a `2dsphere` index and it is created successfully, which I proved by checking `db.Model.getIndexes(): {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "coordinates.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
  },
  "name" : "coordinates.coordinates_2dsphere",
  "ns" : "myDb.myCollection",
  "background" : true,
  "safe" : null,
  "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
 }`
I also tried querying via `coordinates.coordinates` which results in `E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`.

Comment: Umm. Quotes. therefore literally `"coordinates.coordinates"`. it's called ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and how you explicitly reference individual fields in a MongoDB document within nested levels. I already said the index was not required.

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are king, mate! Thank you, thank you, thank you! It actually was the missing quotes. Problem solved, geospatial queries working. If you write it down as an answer, I can accept it as solving my problem.

Comment: I'm sure you mean Queen! Since you looked at my profile, didn't you. Chicks live here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your model but, use ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) instead:

```
Model.find({
    "coordinates.coordinates": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$centerSphere" : [ [ lng, lat], r ]
        }            
    }
},function(err,callback) {

});
```

Comment: I understand that having a field `coordinates` within a field `coordinates` seems odd, but this is due to third party api conformity. I could refrain from using the outer `coordinates` field, but then I'd have to add it to the results later, when passing them to the client. Simply because it is expected to look like this.